# Turning nested rxjs concatMap to aysnc-await?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, rxjs

I always encounter nested concatMap, the latter http requests base on the former results.
See below example, I need get formConfig and then use the formConfig id to get application record, then xxx. Is it more readable and maintainable turning nested rxjs concatMap to aysnc await (***Avoid callback hell***)? Pros and cons? which one is easier to process error handling?

**General nested concatMap**

```
  ngOnInit(){
     this.http.get(`/app-config/${this.appType}`)
     .pipe(
         concatMap(formConfig => {
             this.formConfig = formConfig;
             return this.http.get(`/appl/${this.formConfig.id}`);
         }),
         concatMap(applRec => {
             this.applRec = applRec;
             return this.http.get(`/xxx/${this.applRec.recNo}`)          
         })
        tap((val) => {this.xxx = val})
         ....
     ).subscribe();
  }
```

**Turn to async await toPromise**

```
 constructor(){
   this.init().then();
 }
 async init() {
    this.formConfig = await this.http.get(`/app-config/${this.appType}`).toPromise();
    this.applRec = await this.http.get(`/appl/${this.formConfig.id}`).toPromise();
    this.xxx = await this.http.get(`/xxx/${this.applRec.recNo}`).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: Definitely looks more readable to me, but the change from `ngOnInit` to calling an `init` method in the constructor is probably wrong. Also `.then()` without an argument doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is a very board topic. It is like comparing Promise vs Observable. Observable is certainly more powerful but it takes more skill

Answer (score 1):

`toPromise()` is deprecated and is being removed, so you should probably avoid it. More info on that here: https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated#why-is-this-happening-to-me.

If you want to use `async` / `await` / promises you can use `firstValueFrom()`. The cons of using it are outlined in the docs here: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom

> WARNING: Only use this with observables you know will emit at least one value, OR complete. If the source observable does not emit one value or complete, you will end up with a promise that is hung up, and potentially all of the state of an async function hanging out in memory. To avoid this situation, look into adding something like timeout, take, takeWhile, or takeUntil amongst others.

So the disadvantage of promises is that you need to add a timeout or you risk a memory leak. However, I don't think you have to worry about this when using the observables from the HttpClient service, I've never seen one not emit a value or complete.

Since you're only looking for single values and not observable streams, I don't see any downside to using promises here. You can also just label ngOnInit as `async`.

```js
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.formConfig = await firstValueFrom(this.http.get(`/app-config/${this.appType}`));
    this.applRec = await firstValueFrom(this.http.get(`/appl/${this.formConfig.id}`));
    this.xxx = await firstValueFrom(this.http.get(`/xxx/${this.applRec.recNo}`));
  }
```

Comment: "*you need to add a timeout or you risk a memory leak*" - I don't see how that would be different with Observables. Promises don't leak memory and get garbage-collected just fine if nothing holds onto them that would (not) resolve them. If you *do* hold onto the resolver function but just never call it, well, that memory leak is on you not on the promise.

Comment: @Bergi I think RXJS is trying to say that the enclosing function won't get garbage collected if the promise hasn't resolved, but yeah I don't fully understand. If one of these awaits hangs forever you have bigger problems than memory leaks, the entire app would hang. Maybe if you do `firstValueFrom(...).then(...)` and your promise hangs, the enclosing function never gets cleaned up? But it seems exactly the same as subscribing to an observable.